# pivoting rows to columns and null values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
ID ACTIVITY START_DT  END_DT
1  A        01-01-20  05-01-20
1  B        06-01-20  10-01-20
2  A        11-01-20  15-01-20
2  B        16-01-20  22-01-20
3  A        06-01-20  09-01-20
3  B        13-01-20  16-01-20
```

I want the start date of A and the end date of B, like this:

```
ID START_DT END_DT
1  01-01-20 10-01-20
2  11-01-20 22-01-20
3  06-01-20 16-01-20
```

i did this:

```
select 
 id,
 case when id = 'a' then start_dt end start_dt,
 case when id = 'b' then end_dt   end  end_dt
from table
```

i get this

```
id start_date end_date
1  01-01-20   null
1  null       10-01-20  
2  11-01-20   null
2  null       22-01-20
3  06-01-20   null 
3  null       16-01-20
```

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when id = 'a' then start_dt end) as start_dt,
       max(case when id = 'b' then end_dt   end) as end_dt
from table
group by id;
```